# Run alias command in exec system call

Tags: c, alias

We can create many wrapper scripts to call specific binary files and use alias to point to different string.

My requirement is we need to call the alias string in exec system call.

If we run that string directly in exec call, the system call fails

Ex:

```
af45sp01> alias | grep bulk
bulkactivation=wrap_alias=''\''bulkactivation 1'\'' /iscp/node/bin/isnm_wrapper /iscp/space/scr/issp_bulk_activation'

char *pgm_name = "bulkactivation";
      execl((char*)(const char*)path_name, 
            (char*)(const char*)pgm_name,0);
```

The above execl system call fails. I think it is unable to find alias string in the PATH and that is expected. How to get away from this problem??

Comment: An alias is a shell construct. To run a bash alias, the program that is executed should be `bash -c`

Comment: To use `exec` you need to expand the alias, and run the underlying command the alias is an alias for.

Comment: You need to specifically instruct `bash` to expand alias names in non-interactive shells. Also note that relying on aliases may be a security threat. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498

Comment: Whoever poses such requirements needs to be given some *very* stern looks.

Comment: Probably better to try via exec of ksh or bash and give alias string as arguments. Will try out and let you know

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The usage of ksh/bash with command as options worked like a charm. Thanks